# Augumented Lagrangian Method

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

How should one choose the initial value of lambda(multiplier) while using Augumented Lagrangian Method for constrained optimization?

Comment: Do you have a specific class of problems in mind?

Comment: Not really, I just want to know, for a general constrained problem, how does the initial value of lambda affect the number of iterations and the solution, Is there any thumb rule to choose initial lambda?

Comment: lets say the problem of optimizing a convex function with some linear constraints.

Comment: I believe it depends on the problem. If you have a good guess for a compact set where the optimal dual solution must reside, then choose some value there. Otherwise, I would set it to zero.

Comment: What do you mean by optimal dual solution? Can you please suggest some reference that explains concept of optimal dual.